# Is this sentence grammatically right? ("I mean, now we have Lizzie ,and Cobie are both in it.")

Tags: syntax, spoken-english

I saw the sentence in the movie "I mean, now we have Lizzie ,and Cobie are both in it."

I think that this sentence is grammatically wrong.
I can disassemble this sentence like this.

1. now we have Lizzie and Cobie.
2. Lizzie and Cobie are both in it.

Is my 'idea' right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will very often—perhaps more often than not!—find speakers starting out in one syntactic direction and then changing that direction as their thoughts become clearer. That seems to be what is happening in this line of dialogue:

- *the speaker starts, tentatively* I mean ...
- *the speaker intends to describe the current situation* ... now we have Lizzie ...
- *at this point the speaker decides **how** to describe the situation* ... Lizzie and Cobie are both in it.

The lesson here is that you should not expect strict grammaticality from spontaneous speech, or from composed dialogue which strains to emulate the forms and rhythms of spontaneous speech. If you want your students to master the forms and rhythms of written English, do not set them to watching movies—set them to reading good books.